# Handling http requests and similar async tasks in paused/destroyed Activity/Fragment elements

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a couple of Fragments. "Fragment" A leads to B. Fragment performs a variety of async http request.

If a user decides to close application or navigate back to Fragment A, callbacks of those requests might be triggered on the fragment without view hierarchy attached.

There're a couple of options for solving this kind of issue: cancel requests, check whether view is null.

What are the best practices?

Thanks.